# How to show div slideshow using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slideshow

In the html the div slideshow can change but when the page load first time nothing view as this[image]

after i click button the div show as

[image]

any idea how can I show the first div without clicking the button?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button style="margin-top:70px" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="mySlides" v-for="review in reviews">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" style="padding:0px">
              <h5 class="card-title text-warning">{{review.name}}</h5>
              <p style="text-align:justify">{{review.review}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button style="margin-top:80px" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe setup a code snippet (with the full code) so we can accurately assess the problem at hand? Without that my only guess would either be to set `display: block;` on the initial slide, or call `showDivs(0)` on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code you have presented, the functions look like they should work fine. However, given the premise that it does not and only works when pressing the button then, one way to address the issue is to initialize your slider using the event that triggers when you click the button when the [page is fully loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    plusDivs(1);
});
```